# how to send action message as html format in spring web mvc

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, jstl

I have to display the action message as html format.but the action message takes the html code as string.how to print that html in spring mvc.

Below is my code:

```
@RequestMapping("")
    public ModelAndView openIndex(HttpSession session){

             String msg="<html><span style="color:red">Invalid User</span></html>";
             return new ModelAndView("index","msg",msg);

    }
```

**when i print the msg using jstl it displays like below**

```
<html><span style="color:red">Invalid User</span></html>
```

**But it should be print like below**

```
Invalid User
```

How to achieve the above result?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be using  tag in the jsp.Set the `escapeXml` attribute of to false.The escapeXml attribute determines whether characters <,>,&,'," in the resulting string should be converted to their corresponding character entity codes. Default value is true.

```
<c:out value="${msg}" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
```

Or directly use:

```
${msg}
```

on your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create one div on JSP page with.
2. Then set div background color as red
3. String msg="Invalid User";

   return new ModelAndView("index","msg",msg);
4. On JSP page, you can simply get the value using ${msg}

OR
1. 
        String msg="Invalid User";
        return new ModelAndView("index","msg",msg);

2. use jquery and in document.ready() function you can set msg as a div html
   Something like $('#divID).html(${msg});